# How do you display a dynamic string with Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I have what I hope to be a fairly simple issue to solve, but I've not managed to get it work as I want with my limited knowledge.

I have a C# script piping in a string (a single word) to my python code pasted below. I originally had this code displaying the string on a small OLED display every-time a new string was received (I have now removed this function form the code). I am now wanting to change this so that the string is displayed graphically using Tkinter on a window on my monitor.

My effort below has a window open when a string (message.decode()) is received with the word displayed, but it does not change, it just hangs. Is anyone able to advise on what I need to do to make this automatically change in the same window?

```
from board import SCL, SDA
import busio
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import adafruit_ssd1306
import socket
import sys
import struct

# importing whole module
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

# importing strftime function to
# retrieve system's time
from time import strftime

# Create the I2C interface.
i2c = busio.I2C(SCL, SDA)

# Create a UD socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Connect the socket to the port where the server is listening
server_address = '/tmp/CoreFxPipe_testpipe'
print('connecting to {}'.format(server_address))

try:
    sock.connect(server_address)
except socket.error as msg:
    print(msg)
    sys.exit(1)

try:
    word = ""
    while True:
        # amount_expected = struct.unpack('I', sock.recv(4))[0]
        # print("amount_expected :", amount_expected)

        message = sock.recv(128)
        if message:
            print("Received message : ", message.decode())  # making it a string


            class Window(Frame):
                def __init__(self, master=None):
                    Frame.__init__(self, master)
                    self.master = master
                    self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

                    text = Label(self, text=message.decode())
                    text.place(x=70, y=90)


            root = Tk()
            app = Window(root)
            root.wm_title("tkinter window")
            root.geometry("200x200")
            root.mainloop()




finally:
    print('closing socket...')
    sock.close()
```

Comment: `.mainloop()` is kind of a `while True` itself so that is why `sock.recv` runs only once. Please look at [event driven programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming)

Comment: You might as well try some practice on using functions and see how they are used: having a while True at the module level, while working, is not a great way of having a maintanable program. 

Now, defining a _class_ inside a module-level "while" will certainly raise the eyebrows of a lot of people: that makes next to no sense: you dfine classes elsewhere, and just instantiate them at the point they are needed is the common way.

Comment: Don't use `text` to specify a fixed `str` value for the label. Use `textvariable` to specify a `StringVar` instance whose value you can update elsewhere in your code. It's not clear (at least, not without reading through your entire code) where that `StringVar` should be defined/updated or who should be responsible for holding a reference to it. (Should it be a global, an attribute of some other object, something else?)

Answer (score 1):

You could run the socket consumer (receiver) in a separate `Thread` and put the message it receives into a `Queue`, then consume the message in the tkinter event loop using tkinter's `after` method. Here's an example:

```
...  # I'm leaving out your other imports for brevity's sake
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as tkm
from queue import Queue, Full, Empty
from threading import Thread, Event
from tkinter import ttk


class Root(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  # initialze Tk
        self.title('My App!')
        self.geometry('200x200')
        # tell the app what to do when closing
        self.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.on_close)
        # this queue passes the msg from the worker to the main UI
        self.message_queue = Queue(maxsize=1) 
        # this event flag is how we'll stop the thread worker on exit
        self.stop_event = Event()  
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.text = ttk.Label(self, text='Waiting for a message...')
        self.text.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
        self.consumer_loop_id = None  # placeholder for the consumer 'after' ID
        # this sets how quickly you want the consumer loop to check for updates
        self.loop_rate_ms = 100

        try:
            self.sock.connect(server_address)
        except socket.error as msg:
            tkm.showerror('An Error Occurred', msg)
            self.on_close()  # clean up and quit
        else:
            self.start_worker_thread()  # let's go!
            self.message_consumer()  # start the consumer loop

    # this function will get run in its own thread
    @staticmethod
    def socket_worker(sock, message_queue, stop_event):
        """Receive messages and put them into a lossy queue"""
        # keep running until the stop_event flag is set
        while not stop_event.is_set():  
            try:
                message = sock.recv(128).decode()
                # put msg in queue without blocking
                message_queue.put_nowait(message)  
            except Full:  # queue is full, last message hasn't been consumed yet...
                pass  # too bad, better luck next time
            except socket.error:
                stop_event.set()  # bail

    def start_socket_worker(self): 
        """Launch the worker thread"""
        self.worker_thread = Thread(
            name='Message Worker',  # not necessary, but helpful for debugging!
            target=self.socket_worker,
            args=(self.sock, self.message_queue, self.stop_event,)
        )
        self.worker_thread.start()

    def message_consumer(self):
        """Get messages from the queue and update the UI"""
        try:
            message = self.message_queue.get_nowait()
        except Empty:
            pass  # no message, nothing to do
        else: 
            self.text.config(text=message)  # update the label with the new message
        finally:
            self.consumer_loop_id = self.after(
                self.loop_rate_ms,
                self.message_consumer  # call this method again to keep looping!
            )
    
    def on_close(self):
        if self.consumer_loop_id:
            self.after_cancel(consumer_loop_id)  # stop the consumer loop
        if not self.stop_event.is_set():
            self.stop_event.set()  # stop the worker thread
        
        # NOTE: apparently 'join' is unnecessary for non-daemonic threads!
        # if self.worker_thread.is_alive():
            # self.worker_thread.join()

        self.sock.close()
        self.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Root()
    app.mainloop()  # start the app
```

Comment: +1 for not putting `tkinter` inside the new thread. Also why do call `self.worker_thread.join()`? The thread doesn't have the `daemon` flag so python will wait for it before closing anyways.

Comment: @TheLizzard Hah, thanks for the vote of confidence! And if I'm honest, I've never fully wrapped my head around `join()` and it was more or less a "felt better doing it that not" sort of thing. If I don't need it for non-daemonic threads, that's great - I'll go ahead and remove it!